# Determine if an object exists in a S3 bucket based on wildcard

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

Can someone please show me how to determine if a certain file/object exists in a S3 bucket and display a message if it exists or if it does not exist.

Basically I want it to:

1) Check a bucket on my S3 account such as testbucket

2) Inside of that bucket, look to see if there is a file with the prefix test_ (test_file.txt or test_data.txt).

3) If that file exists, then display a MessageBox (or Console message) that the file exists, or that the file does not exist.

Can someone please show me how to do this?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Using the AWSSDK For .Net I Currently do something along the lines of:

```
public bool Exists(string fileKey, string bucketName)
{
        try
        {
            response = _s3Client.GetObjectMetadata(new GetObjectMetadataRequest()
               .WithBucketName(bucketName)
               .WithKey(key));

            return true;
        }

        catch (Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                return false;

            //status wasn't not found, so throw the exception
            throw;
        }
}
```

It kinda sucks, but it works for now.

Comment: Altered throw(ex) to plain-old throw.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question of using wildcards. How can I check if files exist with same prefix?

Comment: There are a couple of issues here. First is that this technique does not support matching objects based on a common prefix. Second, a fairly common execution path (the file does not exist) will result in an exception being thrown - this has performance implications.

Comment: This answer was from 2010 - The SDK supports Exists now - http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/html/T_Amazon_S3_IO_S3FileInfo.htm

Comment: You need the s3:GetObject permission for this operation. See Specifying Permissions in a Policy. If the object you request does not exist, the error Amazon S3 returns depends on whether you also have the s3:ListBucket permission.

If you have the s3:ListBucket permission on the bucket, Amazon S3 returns an HTTP status code 404 ("no such key") error.

If you don't have the s3:ListBucket permission, Amazon S3 returns an HTTP status code 403 ("access denied") error.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/S3/MS3GetObjectMetadataGetObjectMetadataRequest.html

Comment: @Alex not the .NET-Core SDK

Comment: @AlexfromJitbit this answer is almost 12 years old, and my last comment was 9 years ago!

Comment: I am seeing 404s from Azure Application Insights on this approach. Works, but unnecessary http stack issue

Answer (score 70):

Use the [S3FileInfo.Exists](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/Index.html?page=PS3_IO_S3FileInfo_Exists_NET4_5.html) method:

```
using (var client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(accessKey, secretKey))
{
    S3FileInfo s3FileInfo = new Amazon.S3.IO.S3FileInfo(client, "your-bucket-name", "your-file-name");
    if (s3FileInfo.Exists)
    {
         // file exists
    }
    else
    {
        // file does not exist
    }   
}
```

Comment: If key doesn't exist then AmazonS3Exception exception will be thrown with message 'Forbidden 403'. Pretty silly stuff... But if we are sure that we have access to the bucket we can treat it as 'false'.

Comment: This is a much better solution than the currently top rated on due to the fact it doesn't use exceptions to drive logic. It'll be higher performance.

Comment: @PavelShkleinik - The source available on github is fairly recent:

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/master/AWSSDK_DotNet35/Amazon.S3/IO/S3FileInfo.cs

 - I believe what you say is no longer the case luckily.

Comment: You would get 403 if you don't have ListObjects permission in the bucket.  Otherwise 404 vs non-404 errors could result in undesired information disclosure.

Comment: i know this is an old answer, just note that this solution is based on an exception, it uses GetObjectMetadata which throws an exception if the file doesn't exist https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/6c3be79bdafd5bfff1ab0bf5fec17abc66c7b516/sdk/src/Services/S3/Custom/_bcl/IO/S3FileInfo.cs#L118

Comment: I don't think this solution works with dotnet core, see: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=245007

Answer (score 13):

Not sure if this applies to .NET Framework, but the .NET Core version of AWS SDK (v3) only supports async requests, so I had to use a slightly different solution:

```
/// <summary>
/// Determines whether a file exists within the specified bucket
/// </summary>
/// <param name="bucket">The name of the bucket to search</param>
/// <param name="filePrefix">Match files that begin with this prefix</param>
/// <returns>True if the file exists</returns>
public async Task<bool> FileExists(string bucket, string filePrefix)
{
    // Set this to your S3 region (of course)
    var region = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1;

    using (var client = new AmazonS3Client(region))
    {
        var request = new ListObjectsRequest {
            BucketName = bucket,
            Prefix = filePrefix,
            MaxKeys = 1
        };

        var response = await client.ListObjectsAsync(request, CancellationToken.None);

        return response.S3Objects.Any();
    }
}
```

And, if you want to search a folder:

```
/// <summary>
/// Determines whether a file exists within the specified folder
/// </summary>
/// <param name="bucket">The name of the bucket to search</param>
/// <param name="folder">The name of the folder to search</param>
/// <param name="filePrefix">Match files that begin with this prefix</param>
/// <returns>True if the file exists</returns>
public async Task<bool> FileExists(string bucket, string folder, string filePrefix)
{
    return await FileExists(bucket, $"{folder}/{filePrefix}");
}
```

Usage:

```
var testExists = await FileExists("testBucket", "test_");
// or...
var testExistsInFolder = await FileExists("testBucket", "testFolder/testSubFolder", "test_");
```

Comment: brilliant & elegant solution, thank you!

Comment: CAUTION: "list" requests are 10X more expensive than "get" requests!

Answer (score 11):

This solves it:

List the bucket for existing objects and use a prefix like so.

```
    var request = new ListObjectsRequest()
        .WithBucketName(_bucketName)
        .WithPrefix(keyPrefix);

    var response = _amazonS3Client.ListObjects(request);

    var exists = response.S3Objects.Count > 0;

    foreach (var obj in response.S3Objects) {
        // act
    }
```

Answer (score 11):

I know this question is a few years old but the new SDK handles this beautifully. If anyone is still searching this. You are looking for [S3DirectoryInfo](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/Index.html?page=TS3_IO_S3DirectoryInfo_NET4_5.html&tocid=Amazon_S3_IO_S3DirectoryInfo) Class

```
using (IAmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(accessKey, secretKey))
{
    S3DirectoryInfo s3DirectoryInfo = new Amazon.S3.IO.S3DirectoryInfo(s3Client, "testbucket");
    if (s3DirectoryInfo.GetFiles("test*").Any())
    {
        //file exists -- do something
    }
    else
    {
        //file doesn't exist -- do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: Uses ListObjectsRequest, which is not good. https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/6c3be79bdafd5bfff1ab0bf5fec17abc66c7b516/sdk/src/Services/S3/Custom/_bcl/IO/S3DirectoryInfo.cs

Comment: Well of course it does.  We are trying to see if the object exists without getting it.

Answer (score 3):

I used the following code in C# with Amazon S3 version 3.1.5(.net 3.5) to check if the bucket exists:

```
BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("accessKey", "secretKey");

AmazonS3Config configurationAmazon = new AmazonS3Config();
configurationAmazon.RegionEndpoint = S3Region.EU; // or you can use ServiceUrl

AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, configurationAmazon);


S3DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new S3DirectoryInfo(s3Client, bucketName);
            bucketExists = directoryInfo.Exists;// true if the bucket exists in other case false.
```

I used the followings code(in C# with Amazon S3 version 3.1.5 .net 3.5) the file Exists.

Option 1:

```
S3FileInfo info = new S3FileInfo(s3Client, "butcketName", "key");
bool fileExists = info.Exists; // true if the key Exists in other case false
```

Option 2:

```
ListObjectsRequest request = new ListObjectsRequest();
        try
        {
            request.BucketName = "bucketName";
            request.Prefix = "prefix"; // or part of the key
            request.MaxKeys = 1; // max limit to find objects
            ListObjectsResponse response = s3Client .ListObjects(request);
            return response.S3Objects.Count > 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is a few years old but the new SDK nowdays handles this in an easier manner.

```
  public async Task<bool> ObjectExistsAsync(string prefix)
  {
     var response = await _amazonS3.GetAllObjectKeysAsync(_awsS3Configuration.BucketName, prefix, null);
     return response.Count > 0;
  }
```

Where `_amazonS3` is your `IAmazonS3` instance and `_awsS3Configuration.BucketName` is your bucket name.

You can use your complete key as a prefix.

Comment: Worth noting that this is for .NET Core

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with C#, but I use this method from Java (conversion to c# is immediate):

```
public boolean exists(AmazonS3 s3, String bucket, String key) {
    ObjectListing list = s3.listObjects(bucket, key);
    return list.getObjectSummaries().size() > 0;
}
```

Comment: Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe this would return false for 0 byte (empty) files.

Answer (score 1):

There is an overload for GetFileSystemInfos
Notice this line has filename.*

**var files= s3DirectoryInfo.GetFileSystemInfos("filename.*");**

```
public bool Check()
{
    var awsCredentials = new Amazon.Runtime.BasicAWSCredentials("AccessKey", "SecretKey");

      using (var client = new AmazonS3Client(awsCredentials, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1))
       {
       S3DirectoryInfo s3DirectoryInfo = new S3DirectoryInfo(client, bucketName, "YourFilePath");
                var files= s3DirectoryInfo.GetFileSystemInfos("filename.*");
                if(files.Any())
                {
                    //fles exists
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 s3 = new S3(S3KEY, S3SECRET, false);
 res = s3->getObjectInfo(bucketName, filename);
```

It will return array if file exists

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
    NameValueCollection appConfig = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;

        AmazonS3 s3Client = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(
                appConfig["AWSAccessKey"],
                appConfig["AWSSecretKey"],
                Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1
                );

S3DirectoryInfo source = new S3DirectoryInfo(s3Client, "BUCKET_NAME", "Key");
if(source.Exist)
{
   //do ur stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

my 2 cents

```
    public async Task<bool> DoesKeyExistsAsync(string key)
    {
        ListObjectsResponse response = null;
        try
        {
            response = await _s3Client.ListObjectsAsync(new ListObjectsRequest { BucketName = _settings.BucketName, Prefix = key });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"Error while checking key {key}");
            return false;
        }
        return (response?.S3Objects?.Count > 0);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
using Amazon;
using Amazon.S3;
using Amazon.S3.IO;
using Amazon.S3.Model;

string accessKey = "xxxxx";
string secretKey = "xxxxx";
string regionEndpoint = "EU-WEST-1";
string bucketName = "Bucket1";
string filePath = "https://Bucket1/users/delivery/file.json"

public bool FileExistsOnS3(string filePath)
{
   try
   {
      Uri myUri = new Uri(filePath);
      string absolutePath = myUri.AbsolutePath; // /users/delivery/file.json
      string key = absolutePath.Substring(1); // users/delivery/file.json
      using(var client = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(accessKey, secretKey, regionEndpoint))
      {
         S3FileInfo file = new S3FileInfo(client, bucketName, key);
         if (file.Exists)
         {
            return true;
            // custom logic
         }
         else
         {
            return false;
            // custom logic
         }
      }
   }
   catch(AmazonS3Exception ex)
   {
      return false;
   }
}
```