# Is there an async-friendly way to find if a file exists on S3 in C#

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, async-await

All the answers I've found so far indicate using something basically like:

```
AmazonS3Client client = new AmazonS3Client(accessKey, secretKey, regionEndpoint);       
S3FileInfo s3FileInfo = new S3FileInfo(client, bucketName, fileName);
return s3FileInfo.Exists;
```

(From [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44166893/23512))

However, this looks like it will be completely synchronous. As I'm converting more of our code to async-await, I've found most of the S3 calls have Async versions, but I haven't found an Async version of this call.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: You could make this code async yourself and await on it.  That's usually how I deal with libs that don't have async methods.

Comment: If you are going to async-ify your code, take a look at Stephen Toub's blog post: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/.  Going through Stephen Cleary's blog is a good idea too.  Ideally, you want to do more than just `Task.Run(SomeSynchronousCode());`

Comment: There is the answer in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56318673/1075282